# How do you draw lines between columns (or rows) with PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I've been trying to learn PyQt5 to reimplement an application I did with Tkinter, but with some design differences. Since it's not a complex application, I'd like to make it have a style similar to this small window from GitHub desktop (options on the left side of the window, and the rest in the remaining space):

[image]

I know my colors don't look great now, but I can take care of that later. However, I haven't found out how to draw lines/boxes similar to those, or at lesat in the divisions between my columns/rows.

Here's what I have so far:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QPushButton, QWidget, QFileDialog, QGridLayout, QFrame
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Some Window Title')
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.screen = self.app.primaryScreen()
        self.screen_size = self.screen.size()
        self.screen_width = self.screen_size.width()
        self.screen_height = self.screen_size.height()

        self.setGeometry(
            self.screen_width * 0.1,
            self.screen_height * 0.1,
            self.screen_width * 0.8,
            self.screen_height * 0.8
        )
        self.setStyleSheet('background: #020a19;')

        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.grid.setVerticalSpacing(0)
        self.grid.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.option_button_stylesheet =  '''
            QPushButton {
                background: #020a19;
                color: #c5cad4;
                border-color: #c5cad4;
                border: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
                border-style: outset;
                border-radius: 5px;
                font-size: 15px;
                font-weight: bold;
                padding: 10px;
                margin: 15px;
                width: 2px;

            }

            QPushButton:hover {
                background-color: #00384d;
            }
            '''

        self.placeholder_button_stylesheet = '''
            QPushButton {
                background: #020a19;
                color: #c5cad4;
                border-top: none;
                border-right: 1px;
                border-left:none;
                border-bottom: none;
                border-color: #c5cad4;
                border-style: outset;
                padding: 10px;
                margin: 0px;
                width: 2px;
                height: 100%;

            }

            QPushButton:hover {
                background-color: #020a19;
            }
            '''
        
        self.header_label = QLabel('Some Application')
        self.option_1_button = QPushButton('Option 1')
        self.option_2_button = QPushButton('Option 2')
        self.option_3_button = QPushButton('Option 3')        
        
        self.header_label.setStyleSheet(
            '''
            font-size: 25px;
            color: #c5cad4;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-top: 16px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
            height: 10%;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #c5cad4;
            '''
        )
        self.header_label.setFixedHeight(120)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.header_label, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        

        self.option_1_button.setStyleSheet(self.option_button_stylesheet)
        self.option_1_button.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.option_1_button.setFixedHeight(100)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.option_1_button, 1, 0)

        self.option_2_button.setStyleSheet(self.option_button_stylesheet)
        self.option_2_button.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.option_2_button.setFixedHeight(100)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.option_2_button, 2, 0)

        self.option_3_button.setStyleSheet(self.option_button_stylesheet)
        self.option_3_button.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.option_3_button.setFixedHeight(100)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.option_3_button, 3, 0)

        self.grid.setRowStretch(4, 1)
        
        self.initUI()
        
        self.setLayout(self.grid)
        self.show()

    def initUI(self):
        
        self.greet_text = QLabel('Welcome')
        self.greet_text.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.greet_text.setStyleSheet(
            """
            font-size: 35px;
            color: #c5cad4;
            """
        )
        self.grid.addWidget(self.greet_text, 1, 1, 5, 1)


def run():
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(window.app.exec())

run()
```

As you can see, I'm using `QWidget` as my window element. I know I could use `QMainWindow`, but that changes the way widgets are placed and I'm finding it easier to use `QWidget`. I also don't need a toolbar or anything like that for this app.

How can I draw those lines?

Comment: You should use `QMainWindow` you can put your options as [QDockWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QDockWidget.html) and set it on left, and use the Welcome as the main widget

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but it's good information and Interesting. The main widget can be `QWidget` like I'm doing right now, right? By the way, I think I can draw those lines using `QFrame()` and styling the borders and putting the other widgets on top, but I'm still testing.

Comment: yes, the main widget can be `QWidget` or its inheritance.

Comment: Are you referring to the lines of the main layout (the separation between the header, the left and the right content), or those inside the right side? Note that creating the QApplication *inside* the widget `__init__` is wrong (and I'm bit surprised that your code works, as it should crash for that reason): in order to create QWidgets, an existing QApplication instance must be created *before*.

Comment: @musicamante That's good to know. I'll fix it. Now, about the lines, I mean the lines between the header and the below content and between the left and right side. However, it would be great to know a good way to do all of them. I seem to have made them work with a `QFrame()`, but I'm not sure it's the right/best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt style sheets (QSS) don't provide such a feature, as it's only possible to *style* specific widgets without being able to consider their position within the layout. This is important in your case, as what you want to do is draw the "separation" between layout items.

It is theoretically possible to achieve this by setting a background for the container widget that will be the line color, have all its child widgets drawing their *full* contents with *opaque* colors, and ensure that the layout always has a spacing equal to the width of the line, but if the inner widgets don't respect their full size, they use an alpha channel, or some stretch or further spacing is added, the result would be ugly.

One possibility is to use a QWidget subclass, override its `paintEvent()` and draw those lines with QPainter.

The idea is that we cycle through all layout items, and draw lines that are placed in the middle between the "current" item and the previous.

In the following example I've created a basic QWidget subclass that implements the above concept, depending on the layout used.

Note that I had to make some changes and corrections to your original code:

- as already noted in comments, an existing QApplication is mandatory to allow the creation of a QWidget, and while it's possible to make it an attribute of the object (*before* calling the `super().__init__()`), it is still conceptually wrong;
- highly hierarchical structures in grid layouts should not use individual rows and columns for their direct child objects, but proper sub-layouts or child widgets should be added instead; in your case, the should be only two rows and columns: the header will have a 2-column-span in the first row, the menu will be on the second row (index 1) and first column, the right side in the second column, and the menu buttons will have their own layout;
- setting generic style sheet properties for parent widgets is highly discouraged, as complex widgets (such as QComboBox, QScrollBar and scroll areas children) require that *all* properties are set to properly work; using `setStyleSheet('background: ...')` should always be avoided for parents or the application;
- style sheets that are shared among many widgets should be set on the parent or the application, and proper [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) should always be used;
- the QSS `width` property should be used with care, as it could make widgets partially invisible and unusable;
- if you don't want any border, just use `border: none;`;
- only absolute units are supported for style sheet sizes (see the [`Length`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#length) property type), percent values are ignored;
- setting fixed heights, paddings and margins can result in unexpected behavior; ensure that you carefully read the [box model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-customizing.html#the-box-model) and do some testing to understand its behavior;
- classes should not show themselves automatically during construction, so `show()` should not be called within the `__init__()` (this is not specifically "forbidden" or discouraged, but it's still good practice);
- an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block should always be used, especially when dealing with programs or toolkits that rely on event loops (like all UI frameworks, as Qt is);

Here is a rewriting of your original code:

```
class LayoutLineWidget(QWidget):
    _borderColor = QColor('#c5cad4')

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        # QWidget subclasses *must* do this to properly use style sheets;
        # (see doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#qwidget-widget)
        opt = QStyleOption()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        qp = QStylePainter(self)
        qp.drawPrimitive(QStyle.PE_Widget, opt)
        # end of default painting

        layout = self.layout()
        if not layout or layout.count() <= 1:
            return
        if layout.spacing() < 1:
            layout.setSpacing(1)
            return

        qp.setPen(self._borderColor)
        if isinstance(layout, QBoxLayout):
            lastGeo = layout.itemAt(0).geometry()
            if isinstance(layout, QVBoxLayout):
                for row in range(1, layout.count()):
                    newGeo = layout.itemAt(row).geometry()
                    y = (lastGeo.bottom() 
                         + (newGeo.y() - lastGeo.bottom()) // 2)
                    qp.drawLine(0, y, self.width(), y)
                    lastGeo = newGeo
            else:
                for col in range(1, layout.count()):
                    newGeo = layout.itemAt(row).geometry()
                    x = (lastGeo.right() 
                         + (newGeo.x() - lastGeo.right()) // 2)
                    qp.drawLine(x, 0, x, self.height())
                    lastGeo = newGeo
        elif isinstance(layout, QGridLayout):
            for i in range(layout.count()):
                row, col, rowSpan, colSpan = layout.getItemPosition(i)
                if not row and not col:
                    continue
                cellRect = layout.cellRect(row, col)
                if rowSpan:
                    cellRect |= layout.cellRect(row + rowSpan - 1, col)
                if colSpan:
                    cellRect |= layout.cellRect(row, col + colSpan - 1)
                if row:
                    aboveCell = layout.cellRect(row - 1, col)
                    y = (aboveCell.bottom() 
                         + (cellRect.y() - aboveCell.bottom()) // 2)
                    qp.drawLine(cellRect.x(), y, cellRect.right() + 1, y)
                if col:
                    leftCell = layout.cellRect(row, col - 1)
                    x = (leftCell.right() 
                         + (cellRect.x() - leftCell.right()) // 2)
                    qp.drawLine(x, cellRect.y(), x, cellRect.bottom() + 1)


class Window(LayoutLineWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            Window {
                background: #020a19;
            }
            QLabel#header {
                qproperty-alignment: AlignCenter;
                font-size: 25px;
                color: #c5cad4;
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-top: 16px;
                padding-bottom: 20px;
            }
            QWidget#content {
                border: 1px solid #c5cad4;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
            QPushButton {
                background: #020a19;
                color: #c5cad4;
                border: none;
                border-radius: 5px;
                font-size: 15px;
                font-weight: bold;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            QPushButton:hover {
                background-color: #00384d;
            }
            QWidget#menu > QPushButton {
                width: 180px;
                height: 80px;
            }
        ''')

        mainLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        mainLayout.setSpacing(0)

        self.header_label = QLabel('Some Application', objectName='header')
        self.header_label.setMinimumHeight(120)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.header_label, 0, 0, 1, 2)

        menuContainer = QWidget(objectName='menu')
        mainLayout.addWidget(menuContainer)
        menuLayout = QVBoxLayout(menuContainer)
        menuLayout.setSpacing(15)

        self.option_1_button = QPushButton('Option 1')
        self.option_2_button = QPushButton('Option 2')
        self.option_3_button = QPushButton('Option 3')        

        menuLayout.addWidget(self.option_1_button)
        menuLayout.addWidget(self.option_2_button)
        menuLayout.addWidget(self.option_3_button)
        menuLayout.addStretch()

        rightLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(rightLayout, 1, 1)

        self.content = QStackedWidget()
        self.content.setContentsMargins(40, 40, 40, 40)
        rightLayout.addWidget(self.content)
        rightLayout.addStretch(1)

        self.firstPage = LayoutLineWidget(objectName='content')
        self.content.addWidget(self.firstPage)
        firstPageLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.firstPage)
        spacing = sum(firstPageLayout.getContentsMargins()) // 2
        firstPageLayout.setSpacing(spacing)

        self.other_option_1_button = QPushButton('Other 1')
        self.other_option_2_button = QPushButton('Other 2')
        self.other_option_3_button = QPushButton('Other 3')

        firstPageLayout.addWidget(self.other_option_1_button)
        firstPageLayout.addWidget(self.other_option_2_button)
        firstPageLayout.addWidget(self.other_option_3_button)

        screen = QApplication.primaryScreen()
        rect = QRect(QPoint(), screen.size() * .8)
        rect.moveCenter(screen.geometry().center())
        self.setGeometry(rect)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

This is the visual result:

[image: screenshot of the code result]

Note that the above code will cause calling the `paintEvent()` and its instructions very often, so it's always a good idea to provide some caching. A possibility is to use [QPicture](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpicture.html), which is a sort of "QPainter recorder"; since it completely relies on the C++ implementation, this allows to optimize the painting by drawing the existing content until it's changed.

```
class LayoutLineWidget(QWidget):
    _borderColor = QColor('#c5cad4')
    _paintCache = None
    _redrawEvents = QEvent.LayoutRequest, QEvent.Resize

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() in self._redrawEvents:
            self._paintCache = None
            self.update()
        return super().event(event)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        # QWidget subclasses *must* do the following to properly use style sheets;
        # see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#qwidget-widget
        qp = QStylePainter(self)
        opt = QStyleOption()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        qp.drawPrimitive(QStyle.PE_Widget, opt)

        layout = self.layout()
        if not layout or layout.count() <= 1:
            return
        if layout.spacing() < 1:
            layout.setSpacing(1)
            return

        try:
            qp.drawPicture(0, 0, self._paintCache)
        except TypeError:
            self._rebuildPaintCache()
            qp.drawPicture(0, 0, self._paintCache)

    def _rebuildPaintCache(self):
        layout = self.layout()
        self._paintCache = QPicture()
        qp = QPainter(self._paintCache)
        # from this point, it's exactly the same as above
        qp.setPen(self._borderColor)
        if isinstance(layout, QBoxLayout):
        # ...
```

Further notes:

- the above codes haven't been tested against widgets with different margin/padding settings and complex row/column spans for grid layouts; it might need further fixing;
- one of the hidden features of QGridLayout is that it's possible to set more widgets for each grid "cell"; while this feature can be useful for complex layouts, it has an important drawback: whenever a child widget or layout uses spanning, the layout spacing is ignored, so child items might have inconsistent geometries and the above code might not work as expected;
- don't underestimate the aspects related to the box model, especially when dealing with sizes;
- font sizes should *not* be set in pixels, as screens can have different DPI settings; always prefer device based units: `pt`, `em` or `ex`;

Comment: Awesome. I know some things that were basic about the box model didn't look good and the border styles look redundant. I started learning this today and was probably trying to go too fast. I'll be reading about the information in your comments and implementing the code you shared. When I do that and add some more things and comment here on any related doubt. I think I'll post it in code review to get some comments when I'm done. Would be great if you happen to see the post. Great explanation.

Comment: @TheSprinter QSS are a bit obscure in some ways, their documentation works well for basic implementations, but is poor (and sometimes unreliable) for advanced topics and requires lots of research, experience and deep knowledge of QStyle management. It's extremely powerful as long as you know how it behaves, but as with any wild animal, you have to *really* know it. Studying the sources is an important step. If you're going to submit it on code review, please do add a comment with the post link: the code in my answer is not *that* strict, but I'd be glad to fix it if required.